# INSERT pegando SELECT de duas tabelas com WHERE - MYSQL

Tags: banco-de-dados, mysql

Olá!

Segue meu Insert e abaixo explico o que está acontecendo:

```
INSERT INTO tab_relatorio_ext 
SELECT 
    t1.CODIGO_EXT, 
    t1.TIPO_EXT, 
    t2.NOME_SITUACAO_EXT 
FROM Tab_Coletados_Ext as t1 
JOIN tab_ext_situacao as t2 ON t2.ID_SITUACAO_EXT = t1.SITUACAO_EXT
WHERE t1.TIPO_EXT = 'BC';
```

Eu preciso inserir dados na tabela `TAB_RELATORIO_EXT`, que vem de outras duas tabelas (`T1 e T2`).
Condições:

- campo `t2.nome_situacao_ext`: O ID para trazer essa informação estou passando após o `ON` no meu `select`. Acredito que o erro esteja aqui.
- campo `t1.tipo_ext` for igual a `'BC'`.

O `insert` até funciona, mas quando atende a condição após o `ON` ele já dá um `insert` e depois dá outro quando atender o `Where`. Ou seja, o item está ficando duplicado. Alguém tem alguma sugestão?

Obrigaduuuu!

Comment: o _select_ traz mesmo só uma linha de retorno? se for o caso, joga o que tem no `where` como `and` do `on` que deve resolver =p

Comment: Cara, removi o banco de dados. Criei outro do zero e funcionou da forma que postei mesmo. Puts...programação tem hora que ferve o sangue da gnt. Vlww!